# ¿Como puedo un crear Waveform de audio en php?

Tags: php, imagen, audio

Buenas e visto por Internet, varios generadores de waveform de audio, lamentablemente no e visto ninguno que enseñe como crearlos, e visto que instalando librerías como Lame o FFmpeg, si bien es funcional pero no algo que este buscando al menos cuando uno no tiene acceso al sistema en un hosting. Si bien existe esa manera, se que existe otra que no es necesario instalar ninguna externa librería a php, hay sistemas tipo Soundkid o Musicengine que generan el waveform con php o bueno e obtenido otros que también funcionan así.

En fin, mi punto es que no se si conozcan algún script o tutorial donde pudiera tener información sobre lo que ando buscando.

Mi objetivo e subir música al servidor procesando el audio guardando el archivo de imagen en carpeta donde guardaría la dirección en una base de datos para así utilizarla posteriormente en la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más optimo sería visualizar la waveform en cliente, almacenando solo el archivo audio en servidor, liberandolo de carga,
puedes usar esta herramienta , aunque hay varias : https://wavesurfer-js.org/

saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo adjuntar la info a la que haces referencia en tu propia respuesta asi queda mucho mejor y facilitas la vida a futuros usuarios :)